# no such table: (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am getting the following error: no such table: categories (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM categories.

I have an activity, SplashActivity which loads a second activity Category. On the Category Activity, I am loading a spinner with data from a table [categories] in the database. When the user selects an item on the spinner and it should load a QuestionsActivity which shows questions from the database based on the selection on the spinner.

The database is being copied from the Assets folder. It was working and then suddenly the error started popping up when I put the code to load the Question activity on the 'play' button. I have uninstalled the application from my phone to wipe of the data and reloading still gives the same error.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873626/unable-to-start-activity-android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570005/no-such-table-when-i-add-a-new-table), still no luck getting it to work.

---

This is my logcat

```
06-17 21:15:16.610  16854-16854/zw.co.pindula.funsa E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: categories
06-17 21:15:16.624  16854-16854/zw.co.pindula.funsa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: zw.co.pindula.funsa, PID: 16854
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{zw.co.pindula.funsa/zw.co.pindula.funsa.util.Category}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: categories (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM categories
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: categories (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM categories
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
            at zw.co.pindula.funsa.db.DBHelper.getAllCategories(DBHelper.java:168)
            at zw.co.pindula.funsa.util.Category.loadCategoryData(Category.java:70)
            at zw.co.pindula.funsa.util.Category.onCreate(Category.java:37)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is my DBHelper Class

```
package zw.co.pindula.funsa.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import zw.co.pindula.funsa.quiz.Question;

/**
 * Created by NKT on 03/06/2015.
 */
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static String DB_PATH;// =  "/data/data/zw.co.pindula.funsa/databases/";
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_NAME = "questionsDb";

    //Category Table name
    private static final String TABLE_CATEGORY = "categories";

    private final Context myContext;
    //private static String DB_PATH= Context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist)
        {
            //By calling this method an empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        /*
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH;// + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database doesn't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        */
        //New checkDataBase method
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try{
            String myPath = myContext.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases")+ File.separator + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e){
            System.out.println("Database doesn't exist");
        }

        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH;// + DB_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH;// + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone
        //db.execSQL("DROP D IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        //onCreate(db);
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestionSet(int difficulty, int numQ){
        List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE DIFFICULTY=" + difficulty +
                " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            //Log.d("QUESTION", "Question Found in DB: " + c.getString(1));
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
            q.setAnswer(c.getString(2));
            q.setOption1(c.getString(3));
            q.setOption2(c.getString(4));
            q.setOption3(c.getString(5));
            q.setRating(difficulty);
            questionSet.add(q);
        }
        return questionSet;
    }

    /**
     * Getting and return all the Categories
     * */
    public List<String> getAllCategories(){
        List<String> myCategories = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CATEGORY;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                myCategories.add(cursor.getString(1));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // closing connection
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        // returning categories
        return myCategories;
    }
/*
 * This method sets the questions using the categories
 */
    public List<Question> getQuestionSetCategories(String cat, int difficulty, int numQ){
        List<Question> questionSet = new ArrayList<Question>();
        Cursor c = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE CATEGORY=" + cat +
                " ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT " + numQ, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            //Log.d("QUESTION", "Question Found in DB: " + c.getString(1));
            Question q = new Question();
            q.setQuestion(c.getString(1));
            q.setAnswer(c.getString(2));
            q.setOption1(c.getString(3));
            q.setOption2(c.getString(4));
            q.setOption3(c.getString(5));
            q.setRating(difficulty);
            questionSet.add(q);
        }
        return questionSet;
    }
}
```

This is the Category Activity

```
package zw.co.pindula.funsa.util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import zw.co.pindula.funsa.R;
import zw.co.pindula.funsa.db.DBHelper;
import zw.co.pindula.funsa.quiz.Constants;
import zw.co.pindula.funsa.quiz.GamePlay;
import zw.co.pindula.funsa.quiz.Question;

public class Category extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    Spinner spinner;
    String theCategory; //This is the String to hold the selected category

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);

        loadCategoryData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_category, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
         * Function to load the spinner data from SQLite database
         * */
        private void loadCategoryData() {
            // database handler
            DBHelper db = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());

            // Spinner Drop down elements
            List<String> lables = db.getAllCategories();

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            //dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        }

    public void startGame(View view){


        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        theCategory = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


        if(theCategory==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't select anything: ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent i;

            List<Question> questions = getQuestionSetFromDb();

            //Initialise Game with retrieved question set ///
            GamePlay c = new GamePlay();
            c.setQuestions(questions);
            c.setNumRounds(getNumQuestions());
            ((FunsaApplication)getApplication()).setCurrentGame(c);

            //Start Game Now.. //
            i = new Intent(this, QuestionActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PLAYBUTTON);
            //break;
        }

    }
    private List<Question> getQuestionSetFromDb() throws Error {
        int diff = getDifficultySettings();
        int numQuestions = getNumQuestions();
        DBHelper myDbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }
        List<Question> questions = myDbHelper.getQuestionSetCategories(theCategory, diff, numQuestions);
        myDbHelper.close();
        return questions;
    }

    /**
     * Method to return the difficulty settings
     * @return
     */
    private int getDifficultySettings() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
        int diff = settings.getInt(Constants.DIFFICULTY, Constants.MEDIUM);
        return diff;
    }

    /**
     * Method to return the number of questions for the game
     * @return
     */
    private int getNumQuestions() {
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS, 0);
        int numRounds = settings.getInt(Constants.NUM_ROUNDS, 2); //This sets the number of rounds
        return numRounds;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String selection =adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();//.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        theCategory = selection;
        // Showing selected spinner item
        Toast.makeText(adapterView.getContext(), "You selected: " + selection,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

Comment: try calling the Full name of the table .. DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME

Comment: Try using the dbname before the tablename . Eg : SELECT * from dbname.tablename;

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/).

Comment: `no such table: categories (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM categories` => Create a table named `categories` in your database.

Comment: @ItzikSamara, I have just tried using the full name of the table and there is no change. Will now try the suggestion for using SQLiteAssetHelper

Comment: @CL. Thank you, SQLiteAssetHelper solved my problem.